# jayway 2.2.0 remove brackets in jsonpath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

We just started using 2.2.0 jayway and it seems to have many differences than 0.9.1.

I am trying to get this item: `$.[?(@.errorId=='200')].errorName[0]` which worked in 0.9.1 by returning the value of errorName. In 2.2.0 it returns nothing. If I change it to `$.[?(@.errorId=='200')].errorName` I get back a string WITH brackets "[result]" which does not work for me. What should be the jsonPath in order to return a value and not an array?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jayway json path behavior changed.
Now, whenever you use filter ('?') you will receive a java list in response.
See "Indefinite paths" in https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when

So you have to `.get(0)` on json path result...

Comment: So there is no way to do this with a jsonPath filter expression? You can only do this with code?